# Javascript reset function won't work after successful submission of a web form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new to JavaScript. I am working in Visual Studio with ASP.NET and I have a simple form. I also have a JavaScript function to validate the form and a JavaScript function to reset the form. The validation and submission work fine. However, after submitting the form, I cannot get the JavaScript reset function to work. I have also tried using a regular HTML input button and it does not work. It works fine before a successful submision, but never after.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function resetForm() {
      document.getElementById("accountForm").reset();
}

<asp:Button ID="subBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validateForm()" onclick="subBtn_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="rstBtn" runat="server" Text="Reset"  OnClientClick="resetForm()" oncClick="rstBtn_Click"/>
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using a plain reset button? No script required.

Answer (score 2):

Your reset button has both client side and server side event handlers. Is this necessary? Consider resetting the form with a button that works client side, such as

```
<input type="reset" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the form is being reset, but the controls have default values so they are set when the form is reset.

A reset button will reset all controls to their default value. If you want to clear the defaults so that all the form controls to have no value, then you need to clear all their default values, something like:

```
function clearForm(form) {
  var control, controls = form.elements;

  for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];

    // Don't change value of submit or reset buttons
    if (control.type != 'submit' && control.type != 'reset') {

      if (control.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select') {

        for (var j=0, jLen=control.options.length; j<jLen; j++) {
          control.options[j].defaultSelected = false;
        }             

      } else if (control.defaultChecked) {
        control.defaultChecked = false;

      } else {
        control.defaultValue = '';
      }
    }
  }
  // Now reset the form
  form.reset();
}
```

And pass a reference to the form to the function, so your reset button is something like:

```
<input type="reset" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">
```

Answer (score 0):

It does reset the form, the form initial state after submit has values.

> **reset**
>   Restores a form element's default values. It performs the same action as a reset button.

[spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76767677)

You can write javascript code to clear all the inputs if this is what you like.

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
    e[i].value = "";
}
```

If you can use **jQuery**, it's a lot simpler:

```
$('input[type="text"], textarea, select').val('');
```

Comment: That doesn't affect the defaultValue for most elements but it will reset the displayed label for reset and submit buttons to the default, the OP may wish to keep the set value for those.